# Java regex to parse two levels of structure

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to parse two levels of structure in a string. The input can of form.
`x1:x2:x3::y1:y2:y3` --> where there can be more chaining with `::`

The regex should be able to parse the string through `::` in the first go, and then each group through `:`.
Output should look like:
`x1, x2, x3` and `y1, y2, y3`

I have been able to figure out parsing one level by capturing the group.

```
(^[a-zA-Z\d]+):([a-zA-Z\d]+):([a-zA-Z\d]+$)
```

How do we make it work for two levels of parsing?

On the lighter note, would you prefer just using `Split` to make it simpler? I prefer regex as it has cleaner checks on data organization.

Comment: What is the actual output you want here?  This sort of would determine which approach to take.

Comment: Perhaps like this `\G([a-zA-Z\d]+)(?:::?|$)` https://regex101.com/r/hW09yU/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird, that kind of loses the essence of multiple level of parsing. I would have to run a loop and parse every three groups together. It also doesn't enforce that there should be three strings separated by a ":"

Comment: About the `split()` part: you can still do a `.split("::")` for getting the variable amount of triplets, and then do the `(^...):(...):(...$)` on each of them for verification.